# How to use return keyword in lambda

Tags: java, java-8, return, java-stream, option-type

I have Optional. I want to write code which sounds as follows:
If object is present convert him from Optional to Object and do remaining code with him. If is not present, return code 404. I try do this but is not working. I do not know how to use return statement here.

```
Object objectFromOptional = optional.stream()
                .findFirst().orElse(return ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

Comment: Your approach looks wrong. you manipulate an `Optional<Object>`. It is a not safe type approach because you will probably have to cast it to something more specific to be able to use it.

Comment: The `return` statement has to go outside your lambda. A `return` statement inside a lambda (allowed within curly braces `{}`) will only return from the `{}` block, not from your method.

Answer (score 3):

No need `return` keyword, You can just use :

```
Object objectFromOptional = optional.stream()
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

---

Edit

After OP comment, the suggested solution can be :

```
private static final ResponseEntity<Object> notFound = ResponseEntity.notFound().build(); 
...
Object objectFromOptional = optional
                .orElse(notFound);
```

Or as mentioned in the comments you can use `orElseGet` which took a Supplier like so :

```
Object objectFromOptional = optional
        .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

Comment: Or, if the not found were expensive to construct: `.orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build())`.

Comment: @AndyTurner or, taking the question literally, `.orElseGet(() -> { return ResponseEntity.notFound().build(); })`

Comment: @Kub4k1 can you show us the declaration of optional Object

Comment: Optional<Object> optional = repository.findById(id); Method findById comes from Spring data CRUD repository

Comment: @Kub4k1 in this case optional is not a collection you can't use stream().findFirst() you can just use orElse with the way in my solution

Comment: Unless `ResponseEntity<Object>` is immutable it's better to use a provider to lazily create a new one instance on demand. `.orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build())`

Comment: in Optional cannot be applied
to
(org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object>)
 This error appears on  .orElse(notFound);

Comment: @Kub4k1 not possible I try it in my said and it is fine unless your optional type is deffirent

Comment: I agree @AndyTurner, Ezequiel that would be more wise solution

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like this without `return` and `optional.stream()`

```
Object objectFromOptional = optional.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

Note: As **@Andy** mentioned, `ResponseEntity.notFound().build()` might be an expensive operation